# A Good Embedded DB for Mobile Applications

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, embedded-database

I'm developing an App on windows mobile and android, i needed a database for this app and as of now have shortlisted 3 lite databases.
SQLite
Ultralite (from Sybase)
Oracle Lite

of these 3, i was unable to configure UltraLite with my existing project on VS2008.
i am currently using SQLite with the dll from http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com but i will need a embedded db that is a lot more data intensive. 
thus i thought of using Oracle Lite but i have no idea of the licensing or cost issues as far as Oracle Lite is concerned.

So now i have 2 questions:

1. Can anyone help me with configuring Ultralite for my VS2008 poject (i tried the tutorial - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Win_Mobile5_Database_App.aspx but still keep on getting the error)
2. is there any LEGAL way i can use Oracle Lite for developing my mobile app for free, if not what are the costs?

Comment: Let it be, i finally seem to have figured out UltraLite :-)

Comment: Does that mean you no longer want an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already have solved the issues in your first question.

Regarding your second question Oracle Lite is not free. You can see the prices [here](https://shop.oracle.com/pls/ostore/product?p1=oracledatabaselite&sc=otn_oracledatabaselite).